# How to link assets(images,stylesheet etc) in Views for CodeIgniter 2.1?

Tags: codeigniter, php

I am using CodeIgniter *Version 2.1* & trying to link assets like images,stylesheets, javascript files etc in my views by using, `header.php`:

`<link href="<?php base_url();?>css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

my controller code, calls the view:

```
<?php
class Main extends CI_Controller{
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('header');
}
```

- The view file from which I am trying to load the asset is located
  `../application/views/header.php`.
- the css file is loaded:
  `../application/views/css/style.css`

this does not work. I get **404 - Page not found** error.then, I tried moving `css/style.css` outside `../application` directory in webroot.  To my surpise, having assets in webroot(outsite ../application/views) seems to work nicely.

Now,
My Question is

1. Is having our assets directly in webroot, outsite `../application` directory right approach? If YES/NO, then why?
2. If having assets directly in webroot is a good idea, than should I move `../application/views` directory in webroot as well? How?

**PS:** I am new to CodeIgniter framework, so unaware of the best practices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to put your assets in the webroot folder. When requesting assest from the server (depending on your setup), it will start from the root directory and work it's way down.

```
http://yoursite.com/application/views/css/mystyles.css
```

if it's in the root you only need to go from there

http://yoursite.com/css/mystyles.css

Although it might be worth putting them all inside a folder (/assets) to keep them contained, as well as the ability to write a more effective rewrite rule (if you are trying to remove the index.php from the url) to ignore the single folder instead of all the individual folders (/css, /js, etc)

As for the views folder, it's best if you leave it in the `application` folder as CodeIgniter has a built in loader that automatically checks `/application/views` for the view file when you use the code `$this->load->view('myview')`

Although there are way to move the views folder, if you are new to CI it's probably best to leave it there for now.

Comment: Thanks, moving out assets to webroot seems like a good idea :)

Answer (score 7):

If you see [this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html), the section where `.htaccess` is used to remove `index.php` from the urls, that has a rewrite condition:

```
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
```

In this line, images is a folder that will be ignored while mod-rewriting. So, you can replace it by assets, put all your directly linking files there, and happily use them.

```
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
```

EDIT: my bad, hadn't seen the date the question was asked. nevertheless, should be useful for someone.

Comment: `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)`
when I use this everything is good when I am I am viewing my Controller example: http://website.com/controller but when I use any functions of my controller it doesn't work example: http://website.com/controller/index

Comment: @shaz3e: are you also using `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]` ?

Answer (score 1):

For linking css you can do something like:

```
echo link_tag('css/mystyles.css');
```

Check this for ref: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html

Comment: putting `echo link_tag(css/style.css)` in my view generates the  html 


`<link href="http://localhost/phplogin/css/style.css" 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`.



 This location is located points outside `../application/` directory. Directly in webroot, but my css is located at `../application/views/css/style.css`. Hence, I get **404 - page not found**. Any idea how can I make links to `../application/views` or should I consider moving my views outside `../application`, directly in webroot?