# Codeigniter with single controller error 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, controller

I'm quite a rookie with CodeIgniter, and as per title, I have troubles trying to setup a single controller for my application. It's a very simple static site with couple of pages like "home", "about" and so on...

I have this in my `routes.php` file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "mycontroller";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['(:any)'] = "mycontroller/$1";
```

And this in `mycontroller.php` file:

```
// Home
public function index()
{
    $data['page'] = 'home';
    $this->load->view('template',$data);
}

// about
public function about()
{
    $data['page']  = 'about';
    $data['title'] = 'About Us';
    $this->load->view('template',$data);
}
```

I'm working in a localhost environment, and the CI project is in this folder:

```
http://localhost/local/project/ci-tbs/
```

and I've specified it also in the `config.php` file for the `base_url` parameter.

Now what I'd expect pointing the browser to

```
http://localhost/local/project/ci-tbs/about
```

is to find the "About Us" page, instead I got a 404 error. Pointing to the base address corectly gives me the "Home" page.

What am I doing wrong?

Is it sensed to use a single controller istead of 1 per page? I'd totally do that in a quick way to fix, still I'm quite baffled by the fact that I can't understand what I am doing wrong and why it's not working. I'd like to simple set everything in one controller, one method per page.

I've already seen this topic asked here in SO, like using regular expressions in the route `$route['(.*)'] = "mycontroller/$1";`, but nothing really worked for my case wich I think is quite basic (so basic I'm sure my error is so gross that it will be quite embarrassing :P ).

Additional info:

I have in the folder an .htaccess file picked *as is* from the Html5 Boilerplate, tried with and without it but 404 is always there. I'm using XAMPP as local environment.

---

### For answer

As mentioned by @Vincent Decaux in the answer, the deal to fix this was to add index.php in the url, the other interesting part is

> Create your .htaccess file to "hide" index.php

This way I've resolved another small issue for the pages with missing findings for the assets files, so I used the following rule in the .htaccess file, redirecting all requests to the index.php file and excluding files in assets folder and images, along with robots.txt as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11846150/1262357

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

hope this helps others with same problems I had!

Comment: Are you having the apache's 404 or ci's 404?

Comment: But he has no htaccess telling to redirect requests to index.php.. so, it must be apache trying to access some file/dir that doesn't exists.

Comment: Can you try the link : http://localhost/local/project/ci-tbs/index.php/about ?

Comment: It *should* be CI 404, but in .htacces from h5bp there is a rule for 404, `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html`, and I have a 404.html file in the folder.

Comment: @VincentDecaux it worked! Strange thou that as per documentation on CI site it is not specified to include index.php nor mentioned to include  a rule in .htaccess for the index.php IRC

Comment: Cancel my above post, THERE IS a sort of mention to it in the reall bottom line of the page at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/static_pages.html, where they say "Now visit **index.php**/about", so blind I'm sorry... put your answer in @VincentDecaux so i can accept it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentionned in my comment, it seems to work using :

```
localhost/local/project/ci-tbs/index.php/about
```

Create your .htaccess file to "hide" index.php.